# Statistics update - worthwhile on a high activity table or not?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, statistics, maintenance

I have a table with 1.5 billion records which is sampled at 1%. Said table receives over 200-300k insert/update/deletes per hour. Within a couple of hours, the statistics are auto updated as it reaches SQL Server's threshold and samples 1.5 milion rows (0.1%). It then auto updates 4-5 times further that day.

My question - is it worthwhile including said table in our daily maintenance job, for it to just be blown away in an hour or two?

I understand that I could persist the sample rate, but the auto update would likely cause issues sampling 10x higher during periods of high activity.

I could sample at a similar percent, around 0.1% each morning, or I could simply save some time in my maintenance window, remove it from the stats update and allow SQL Server to update when it is ready?

Opinions/previous experience welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: I'd say sampling at such a low percentage is about as meaningful as not doing statistics updates at all.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Are auto update statistics causing any issues with Query execution performance?